# How to get build drop folder using changeset number in TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

So I have a change in our build in TFS. I checked it in and it is completed. I know the file I updated and manage to get the history of my check-in. Now I want to get the build drop folder using my changeset number based on the file history records.

Comment: I am not sure that I totally understand your request. Are you looking to find the latest build that contains your changeset? Or the CI build that was triggered by your checkin? There is no greater that the latter still exists...

Comment: I think the latter part is more appropriate..

Comment: As these builds are cleaned automatically and it is inappropriate to keep everything your ask is non viable even if technically possible